# Generating primes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes

I have been learning Haskell over the last few days, through Learn You A Haskell. I've been attempting to complete some Project Euler problems, some of which require primes. However the function I have written to try to generate some (in this case primes below 20000) isn't outputting correctly. When I run it, `GHCi` returns **'[1, '** and seemingly doesn't terminate. The code I am using is:

```
sieve :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
sieve 20000 list = list
sieve n (x:xs) = sieve (n+1) $ x:(filter (\q -> q `mod` n /= 0) xs)

primesto20000 = sieve 2 [1..20000]
```

And then I am calling `primesto20000`. I understand that the function may be inefficient, I am mainly asking for help on syntactic/process errors that I must have made. 
Thankyou

Comment: I'm not sure why this function doesn't seem to terminate, but I can see why it outputs only 1, isn't it because you filter out the prime numbers along with their derivatives?

Comment: I was intending to append the prime (i.e. the first number in the list) using the x: before the filter function, which was only acting on the rest of the list, xs. How would I do that? @KimitsuDesu

Comment: As a side note, this is not a sieve.  It's simply a trial division prime generator.

Comment: BTW, you might want to check [this great article](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) if you care about performance latter on. The algorithm you are using is worse then trial division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're filtering out multiples of *every* number, not just prime numbers. You want to check divisibility by `x`, not by `n`. (In fact, I'm not sure you need `n` in the `sieve` function at all; just make your `primesto20000` function generate the appropriate input list, and pass that.)

Comment: I just tried using q `mod` x, and it resulted in the function terminating, but only returning [1]

Comment: Try passing it the list `[2..20000]` as input instead. I think the 1 step is filtering out everything.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code:

- Because its time complexity (quadratic I guess), it doesn't finish in a reasonable time and it seems that it just hangs. If you replace 20000 with 200, it'll finish, but the result will be `[1]`.
- The other problem is that for each `n` you want to filter all numbers divisible by `n` that are *larger* than `n`. Without this condition, you filter `n` itself, which has the result that you filter out all numbers.

A corrected version could look like (with a parametrized limit):

```
limit :: Integral a => a
limit = 20000

sieve :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
sieve n list | n == limit
    = list
sieve n (x:xs)
    = sieve (n+1) $ x : (filter filt xs)
  where
    -- filter everything divisible by `n`, but not `n` itself.
    filt q = (q <= n) || (q `mod` n /= 0)

primesto20000 = sieve 2 [1..limit]
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, its very helpful seeing good examples of Haskell code